# cannot watch hulu on firefox after fresh install on 14.04

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I just installed ubuntu and decided to watch hulu, I just got a white box. No flash options (or anything) appear when I right click. Other flash apps work fine, though when I right click to change settings on them they won't let me interact with the in-flash popup that appears. With Chromium, it tells me to update flash, after doing so it works fine. Here is the terminal code that displays when I try to load the hulu webpage in firefox.

```
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
l@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:57:945
sa/wa<.whenReady@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:2733
a/</<.init@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:88:2943
a/u.create@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:88:952
sa@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:2503
a/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:3697
a/h.fire/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:80:944
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
a/h.fire@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:80:907
s@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1314
a/</<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1626
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
a/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1428
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
l@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:57:945
sa/wa<.whenReady@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:2847
a/</<.init@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:88:2943
a/u.create@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:88:952
sa@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:2503
a/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:90:3697
a/h.fire/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:80:944
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
a/h.fire@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:80:907
s@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1314
a/</<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1626
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
a/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:129:1428
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
.send@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2883:1
.ajax@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2789:8
Hulu.Beacon.sendBeacon@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:9809:46
Hulu.Beacon.trackStandardBeacon@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:9785:1
.trackSessionStart@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11242:1
._onSessionIDChanged@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11296:1
.startSessionChecker@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11212:111
@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11303:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f</<.ready@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:439:1
f</B@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:617:51
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
.send@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2883:1
.ajax@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2789:8
Hulu.Beacon.sendBeacon@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:9809:46
Hulu.Beacon.trackStandardBeacon@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:9785:1
.trackSessionStart@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11242:1
._onSessionIDChanged@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11296:1
.startSessionChecker@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11212:111
@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11303:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f</<.ready@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:439:1
f</B@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:617:51
Vector smash protection is enabled.

(firefox:2098): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkContainerClass::add not implemented for `GtkSocket'

(firefox:2098): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion 'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(firefox:2098): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_set_back_pixmap: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(firefox:2098): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_socket_get_id: assertion 'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (socket)' failed

(firefox:2098): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_socket_get_id: assertion 'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (socket)' failed
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
l@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:57:945
a/ha<.process@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:135:5446
y/</ka@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2121
y/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2137
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
y@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:1597
a/<.parse@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2615
a/<.parse@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:151:1136
ba/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:97:1607
r/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:95:733
window.fbAsyncInit/<@http://www.hulu.com/watch/378762#i0,p0,d0:256:13
.on/e@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1470:20
f.event.dispatch@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1307:134
f.event.add/i@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1215:77
f.event.trigger@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1278:163
.trigger/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1512:1
f</<.each@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:525:28
f</e.prototype.each@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:388:8
.trigger@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:1511:1
.run@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:1193:5
@http://www.hulu.com/watch/378762#i0,p0,d0:226:9
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f</<.ready@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:439:1
f</B@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:617:51
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
b.checkFrame@http://tags.bkrtx.com/js/bk-coretag.js:2:6365
l.doTag@http://tags.bkrtx.com/js/bk-coretag.js:2:39769
window.bk_doJSTag@http://tags.bkrtx.com/js/bk-coretag.js:2:41227
Hulu.Tracking.Contextual._fireBlueKai@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11848:35
Hulu.Tracking.Contextual.fireTrackingForPage@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11798:17
Hulu.Views.Watch<.fireContextualTracking@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/i18n/en-us/application-e2d7802a66dec7bcc8be72510242030c.js:15247:67
Hulu.Views.BaseView<.markAddedToDomTree@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/i18n/en-us/application-e2d7802a66dec7bcc8be72510242030c.js:15007:56
HuluRouter.Router<._afterSwap@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:978:338
HuluRouter.Router<._checkTask/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:951:1
HuluRouter.Router<._criticalBlock/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:902:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f.Callbacks/p.fire@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:678:8
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14043:39
Hulu.Utils.runAfterInit@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2469:18
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14042:5
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/n<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14064:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
Hulu.Ajax.call/h</h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2129:60
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
w@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2726:49
.send/d@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2904:6
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
Hulu.GDN.loadInIframe@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11768:1
Hulu.GDN.trackConversion@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:11778:12
b@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:5943:2
Backbone.Events.triggerSafe@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:5923:13
HuluRouter.Router<._afterSwap@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:988:148
HuluRouter.Router<._checkTask/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:951:1
HuluRouter.Router<._criticalBlock/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:902:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f.Callbacks/p.fire@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:678:8
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14043:39
Hulu.Utils.runAfterInit@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2469:18
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14042:5
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/n<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14064:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
Hulu.Ajax.call/h</h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2129:60
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
w@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2726:49
.send/d@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2904:6
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
k@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:71:1288
a/u<.process@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:140:1975
y/</ka@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2121
y/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2137
x@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:37:982
y@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:1597
a/<.parse@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:133:2615
a/<.parse@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:151:1136
ba/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:97:1607
r/<@http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.0&appId=40582213222:95:733
Hulu.Social.parseXFBML@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14892:29
@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:15025:28
b@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:5943:2
Backbone.Events.triggerSafe@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:5923:13
HuluRouter.Router<._afterSwap@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:988:148
HuluRouter.Router<._checkTask/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:951:1
HuluRouter.Router<._criticalBlock/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:902:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
f.Callbacks/p.fire@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:678:8
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h/<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14043:39
Hulu.Utils.runAfterInit@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2469:18
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14042:5
Hulu.PageInfo.PageConfigStore.fetch/n<@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:14064:1
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
Hulu.Ajax.call/h</h@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-c2cab5ebdc7c8b9b2241363cde6007cd.js:2129:60
f.Callbacks/o@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:629:29
f.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:675:66
w@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2726:49
.send/d@http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-ed289c2aa474431ba560123772f5fce7.js:2904:6
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
```